# `(<*>)` definition for the Applicative functor?

Tags: haskell, applicative

Some Haskell source code (see [ref](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html#Applicative)):

```
-- | Sequential application.
--
-- A few functors support an implementation of '<*>' that is more
-- efficient than the default one.
(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
(<*>) = liftA2 id

-- | Lift a binary function to actions.
--
-- Some functors support an implementation of 'liftA2' that is more
-- efficient than the default one. In particular, if 'fmap' is an
-- expensive operation, it is likely better to use 'liftA2' than to
-- 'fmap' over the structure and then use '<*>'.
liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
liftA2 f x = (<*>) (fmap f x)
```

Three things seem to be quite confusing to me:

1) `(<*>)` is defined in terms of `liftA2`, where `liftA2` is defined in terms of `(<*>)`. How does it work? I see no obvious "recursion-break" case...

2) `id` is an `a -> a` function. Why is it passed into `liftA2` as an `(a -> b -> c)` function?

3) `fmap id x` always equals `x`, since functors must preserve appropriate identities. Thus `(<*>) (fmap id x)` = `(<*>) (x)` where `x` = `f a` - an `a`-typed functor itself (by the way, how can `a`-typifying of the functor can be explained from the pure category theory's point of view? functor is just a mapping between categories, it has no further "typification"... seems like it is better to say - "a container of type `a` with an (endo)functor defined for each instance of asummed category `Hask` of well-defined Haskell types). So `(<*>) (f a)` while by definition `(<*>)` expects `f(a' -> b')`: thus, the only way to make it work is to deliberately bound `a` to be an `(a' -> b')`. However when I run `:t \x -> (<*>) (fmap id x)` in the `gchi`, it spits out something mind-blowing: `f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` - which I fail to explain.

---

Can someone step by step explain how does that work and why it even compiles? 
P.S. Category theory terms, if needed, are welcome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For question 1, you left out a very important piece of context.

```
class Functor f => Applicative f where
    {-# MINIMAL pure, ((<*>) | liftA2) #-}
```

Those definitions you quoted belong to a class. That means instances can override them. Furthermore, the MINIMAL pragma says that in order to work, at least one of them must be overridden in the instance. So the breaking of the recursion happens whenever one is overridden in a particular instance. This is just like how the `Eq` class defines `(==)` and `(/=)` in terms of each other so that you only need to provide a definition for one in a hand-written instance.

For question two, `a -> b -> c` is shorthand for `a -> (b -> c)`. So it unifies with (let's rename variables to avoid collision) `d -> d` as `(b -> c) -> (b ->c)`. (tangentially, that's also the type of `($)`.)

For three - you're absolutely right. Keep simplifying!

```
\x -> (<*>) (fmap id x)
\x -> (<*>) x
(<*>)
```

So it shouldn't really be a surprise ghci gave you the type of `(<*>)` back, should it?

Comment: Regarding the second one. So `a -> (b -> c)` has a special case - when `a` is actually `(b -> c)`, right? Then it will look like: `a = (b -> c) -> (b -> c)`.

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov It's the other way around: `a -> a` can be unified with another type such that `a` = `b -> c`, making `a -> a` = `(b -> c) -> (b -> c)`.

Answer (score 6):

> 1) `(<*>)` is defined in terms of `liftA2`, where `liftA2` is defined in terms of `(<*>)`. How does it work? I see no obvious "recursion-break" case...

It's not recursion. In your instance of `Applicative` you can either define both of them or just one. If you define just `(<*>)` then `liftA2` is defined from `(<*>)`, and vice versa.

> 2) `id` is an `a -> a` function. Why is it passed into `liftA2` as an `(a -> b -> c)` function?

Unification works as follows,

> ```
> (<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
> (<*>) = liftA2 id
>
> liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
> ```

```
id     :  u -> u 
liftA2 : (a -> (b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
------------------------------------------------------
u = a
u = b->c

id     :  (b->c) -> (b->c)
liftA2 : ((b->c) -> (b->c)) -> f (b->c) -> f b -> f c
------------------------------------------------------

liftA2 id : f (b->c) -> f b -> f c
```

> 3.
>
> ```
> liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
> liftA2 h x = (<*>) (fmap h x)
> ```

Renamed the first argument from `f` to `h`, to prevent confusion since `f` also shows in the type

```
h    :: a -> (b -> c)
x    :: f a
fmap :: (a -> d) -> f a -> f d
------------------------------
d  = b -> c
h    :: a -> (b->c)
x    :: f a
fmap :: (a -> (b->c)) -> f a -> f (b->c)
----------------------------------------
fmap h x :: f (b -> c)


fmap h x :: f (b -> c)
(<*>)    :: f (b -> c) -> f b -> f c
-------------------------------------
(<*>) fmap h x  :: f b -> f c
```

---

**Edit:**

**Consistency**

To show the consistency of both formulas, first lets first rewrite `liftA2` into something simpler. We can use the formula below to get rid of `fmap` and use only `pure` and `<*>`

```
fmap h x = pure h <*> x
```

and it's best to put all points in the definition. So we get,

```
  liftA2 h u v  
= (<*>) (fmap h u) v
= fmap h u <*> v
= pure h <*> u <*> v
```

So we want to check the consistency of,

```
u <*> v      = liftA2 id u v 
liftA2 h u v = pure h <*> u <*> v
```

For the first we need the property that `pure id <*> u = u`

```
  u <*> v 
= liftA2 id u v 
= pure id <*> u <*> v
= u <*> v
```

For the second we need a property of `liftA2`. Properties of applicative are usually given in terms of `pure` and `<*>` so we need to derive it first. The required formula is derived from `pure h <*> pure x = pure (h x)`.

```
  liftA2 h (pure x) v 
= pure h <*> pure x <*> v 
= pure (h x) <*> v
= liftA2 (h x) v
```

This requires `h : t -> a -> b -> c`. The proof of consistency becomes,

```
  liftA2 h u v 
= pure h <*> u <*> v
= pure h `liftA2 id` u `liftA2 id` v   
= liftA2 id (liftA2 id (pure h) u) v 
= liftA2 id (liftA2 h u) v 
= liftA2 h u v
```

Comment: Seems like there is a typo in your type-deduction: when you state that `(<*>) fmap h x  :: f c` (just beyond the 'Edit' section), you probably mean that `(<*>) fmap h x :: (f b -> f c)`?

Comment: @SerejaBogolubov ops! fixed. Thank you!

Comment: bth, nice consistency proof. is it all by your own or it comes from some science paper? in case it does, can you please share that one too?

Comment: thanks! nah I just wrote it down. For the first part, search for "type inference" and "unification", for the second you need to know the [applicative laws](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Applicative_functors#Applicative_functor_laws) and then it's a bit of algebraic manipulation.

Answer (score 4):

> 1) `(<*>)` is defined in terms of `liftA2`, where `liftA2` is defined in terms of `(<*>)`. How does it work? I see no obvious "recursion-break" case...

Each instance is responsible for overriding at least one of the two. This is documented in a machine-readable way in the pragma at the top of the class:

```
{-# MINIMAL pure, ((<*>) | liftA2) #-}
```

This pragma announces that instance writers must define at least the `pure` function and at least one of the other two.

> `id` is an `a -> a` function. Why is it passed into `liftA2` as an `(a -> b -> c)` function?

If `id :: a -> a`, we can choose `a ~ d -> e` to get `id :: (d -> e) -> d -> e`. Traditionally, this particular specialization of `id` is spelled `($)` -- maybe you've seen that one before!

> 3) ...

I don't... actually see any contradiction set up in the facts you state. So I'm not sure how to explain away the contradiction for you. However, you have a few infelicities in your notation that might be related to mistakes in your thinking, so let's talk about them briefly.

You write

> Thus `(<*>) (fmap id x)` = `(<*>) (x)` where `x` = `f a`.

This is not quite right; the *type* of `x` is `f a` for some `Functor f`, but it is not necessarily *equal to* `f a`.

> by the way, how can `a`-typifying of the functor can be explained from the pure category theory's point of view? functor is just a mapping between categories, it has no further "typification"... seems like it is better to say - "a container of type a with an (endo)functor defined for each instance of assumed category Hask of well-defined Haskell types

A functor constitutes two things: a mapping from objects to objects, and a mapping from arrows to arrows that is compatible with the object mapping. In a Haskell `Functor` instance declaration like

```
instance Functor F where fmap = fmapForF
```

the `F` is the mapping from objects to objects (objects in both the source and target categories are types, and `F` is a thing which takes a type and produces a type) and the `fmapForF` is the mapping from arrows to arrows.

> I run `:t \x -> (<*>) (fmap id x)` in the gchi, it spits out something mind-blowing: `f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b` - which I fail to explain.

Well, you already observed that `fmap id x = x`, which means `\x -> (<*>) (fmap id x) = \x -> (<*>) x`. And for any function `f`, `f = \x -> f x` (up to some niggles that aren't important right now), so in particular `\x -> (<*>) (fmap id x) = (<*>)`. So ghci gives you the type of `(<*>)`, as it should.

Answer (score 2):

Here I have to disagree with the GHC devs on their coding style :)

I would like to argue that one should never write

```
ap = liftA2 id
```

but, instead, use the equivalent

```
ap = liftA2 ($)
```

since the latter makes it clear that we are lifting the application operation.

(Actually, for very technical reasons GHC devs can not use `$` here in this internal module, as pointed out below in the comments. So, at least they have a very good reason for their choice.)

Now, you might wonder why `id` can be used instead of `$`. Formally, we have

```
($) f x
= f x
= (id f) x
= id f x
```

hence, eta-contracting `x` then `f`, we get `($) = id`.

Indeed, `($)` is a "special case" of `id`.

```
id :: a -> a
-- choose a = (b -> c) as a special case
id :: (b -> c) -> (b -> c)
id :: (b -> c) -> b -> c
($):: (b -> c) -> b -> c
```

Hence, the main difference is: `id` is the identity on any type `a`, while `($)` is the "identity" on any functional type `b -> c`. The latter is best visualized as a binary function (application), but it can equivalently be considered a unary function (identity) on a function type.

Comment: Apparently `($)` is not used in that particular place due to GHC-specific shenanigans -- see the comment [at the beginning of `GHC.Base`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/GHC.Base.html).